# Change or disable Content Security Policy in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, catalina

Trying to make my own userscripts, running them in the browser console and connect to `ws://localhost:*` servers, but the Content Security Policy always ruins my day.

How do I disable it in Safari?

Or change them to include `ws://localhost:*` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible in Safari, I had to install Firefox Developer Edition and [change it there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27324485/3310334):

> by disabling `security.csp.enable` in the `about:config` menu

Which you access of course by typing `about:config` into the URL bar.